# Replacing a string in a file that contains ${user.home} using sed in Linux

Tags: xml, bash, sed, xmlstarlet

I would like to replace string in file contains ${user.home} using sed in Linux but I'm unable to do it. I tried below options using sed but failed.

## The input file:

```
<property name="dev.home"  value="${user.home}"/>
```

## Tried code to replace `${user.home}`:

```
sed -i "s/$${user.home}/r_str/g" 1.xml
sed -i "s/${user.home}/r_str/g" 1.xml
sed -i "s/\$\{user\.home\}/r_str/g" 1.xml
```

## Actual:

```
<property name="dev.home"  value="${user.home}"/>
```

## Expected:

```
<property name="dev.home"  value="/dev"/>
```

Comment: Try your last option with single quotes ‘ instead of double “

Comment: Bash does not allow a `'.'` as part of a variable name.

Comment: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858)

Comment: Choose the right tool first. I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet or something comparable).

Comment: they're asking how to replace a string in a file; it has nothing to do with bash not using '.' in the variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to escape the curly braces `{}`

```
echo '${user.home}' | sed "s/\${user.home}/lol$/"
lol$
```

Answer (score 2):

Find and update attribute with xmlstarlet:

```
xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl --update 'property[@value="${user.home}"]/@value' --value '/dev' file
```

Output:

```
<property name="dev.home" value="/dev"/>
```